# Short URL that will always get me to a Gmail login screen?

Tags: gmail, login

What short URL can I type in so that I always get to a Email + Password login screen for Gmail?

Here is my problem - In Chrome, when I enter `gmail.com` into the address bar, I am redirected to a different page. Many times I am not directed to the same exact page, even if I do it within the same minute on the same browser, in the same session. I usually do this within an incognito window (I don't sign into Chrome).

Most of the time I get redirected to something like the following URL where I am presented with `Email` + `Password` input boxes.

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1

Sometimes I get redirected to the following URL where I must then click "Sign In" at the top.

https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html

However, today I got redirected to something like the first URL (I didn't copy it) where I was presented with an **Email input box only* *(no Password input)*. It broke my login manager (KeePass + chromeIPass). I tried the experiment over and over for a few minutes and kept getting this single-input signin page. Then, it went away.

Comment: seems u are logging in your second gmail account,logout the first account and just type mail.google.com u would be redirected over there,in general it would load google apps like youtube,google plus at background thats why it was resulted with url change at address bar

Comment: it seems like your router was hacked ... please see my answer in the following link http://superuser.com/questions/785685/scary-adware-all-links-in-websites-using-google-analytics-goes-to-ad-page/854470#854470

Comment: not a hack that is a change in 42 it forces redirect to accounts.google.com  for secure login

Comment: accounts.google.com used to have a double input login screen. It still does if you go there in a particular browser. It seems like with the latest Chrome, it's a single input at a time and KeePass/chromeIPass doesn't detect the user/password fields. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/913600/38570).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Article: How to Get Back The Old Gmail Login Screen
url: http://www.hacktabs.com/how-to-get-back-the-old-gmail-login-screen/

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/

Comment: Answers that are just links that point to another resource are not very good answers. What happens when the link stops working?

Answer (score 3):

Google presents a normal login screen when I spoof Chrome's User Agent to make the site (accounts.google.com) think that Chrome is IE9.

So, it seems like this is some special login that they are providing for Chrome users but unfortunately it is breaking my password manager (KeePass).

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with an already logged-in session because I have deleted all browser history in Chrome and I still get the single-input-at-a-time login page (unless I change my user agent). They also might be A/B testing on me.